# Function(JS) only works for the highest div/quote

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So I have this function where words in a Blockquote have a blur effect when the page is opened, but my problem is, that I want this function to work for all Blockquotes and different divs but it dont works, only for the highest one in the html. I tried to find solutions but couldn't find on that could help me or i did not understand at all.

How can I fix this ?

```js
function splitWords() {
  let quote = document.querySelector("blockquote q");
  quote.innerText.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
  quotewords = quote.innerText.split(" "),
  wordCount = quotewords.length;
  quote.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i=0; i < wordCount; i++) {
    quote.innerHTML += "<span>"+quotewords[i]+"</span>";
    if (i < quotewords.length - 1) {
      quote.innerHTML += " ";
    }
  }
  quotewords = document.querySelectorAll("blockquote q span");
  fadeWords(quotewords);
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function fadeWords(quotewords) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(quotewords, function(word) {
    let animate = word.animate([{
      opacity: 0,
      filter: "blur("+getRandom(2,5)+"px)"
    }, {
      opacity: 1,
      filter: "blur(0px)"
    }],
    {
      duration: 1000,
      delay: getRandom(500,3300),
      fill: 'forwards'
    }
   )
  })
}


splitWords();
```

```css
.border {

 width:100%;

 height:300px;
 background-color:#b2800a;
 min-width:1200px;


}

.borderimg {
 width:100%;
 content:url("border.png");

 min-width:1200px;
}
.background

{

 width:100%;
 content:url("Background.png");

}
body {
 background-color:#b2800a;
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
 min-width:auto;
}


.header
{
position:absolute;
font-size:70;
color:white;
left 1000px;



 opacity: 0.7;

}



*
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

blockquote {
  font-size: 3rem;

}

blockquote q {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
}
blockquote q span {
  will-change: opacity, filter;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(0px);
}
q {

  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}
q:before {
    content: open-quote;
    margin-right: .8rem;
}
q:after {

}
q:before, q:after {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.text1 {
font-size:80px;
top:160px;

color:white;
position:absolute;
opacity: 0.7;


}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Name</title>
<body class="body">
</head>

<div  class="header"><blockquote><q>Creativity is my way to say hi</q></blockquote></div>
<div  class="text1"><blockquote><q>Welcome on my site</q></blockquote></div>






<script type="text/javascript">

splitWords();


</script>





<div class="background"></div>



<div class="borderimg"></div>

<div class="border"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MasterDarkNight [You should not leave such comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253833). I've flagged your as "no longer needed".

Comment: Ok , sorry , next time I'll not do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where I made changes,

```
  let quote = [ ] ;
  quote = document.querySelectorAll("blockquote q");
  for (let x = 0 ; x < quote.length ; x++) {
```

```js
function splitWords() {
  let quote = [ ] ;
  quote = document.querySelectorAll("blockquote q");
  for (let x = 0 ; x < quote.length ; x++) {
  quotewords = quote[x].innerText.split(" "),
  quote[x].innerHTML = "";
  for (let i=0; i < quotewords.length; i++) {
    quote[x].innerHTML += "<span>"+quotewords[i]+"</span>";
    if (i < quotewords.length - 1) {
      quote[x].innerHTML += " ";
    }
  }
  quotewords = document.querySelectorAll("blockquote q span");
  fadeWords(quotewords);
}
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function fadeWords(quotewords) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(quotewords, function(word) {
    let animate = word.animate([{
      opacity: 0,
      filter: "blur("+getRandom(2,5)+"px)"
    }, {
      opacity: 1,
      filter: "blur(0px)"
    }],
    {
      duration: 1000,
      delay: getRandom(500,3300),
      fill: 'forwards'
    }
   )
  })
}


splitWords();
```

```css
.border {

 width:100%;

 height:300px;
 background-color:#b2800a;
 min-width:1200px;


}

.borderimg {
 width:100%;
 content:url("border.png");

 min-width:1200px;
}
.background

{

 width:100%;
 content:url("Background.png");

}
body {
 background-color:#b2800a;
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
 min-width:auto;
}


.header
{
position:absolute;
font-size:70;
color:white;
left 1000px;



 opacity: 0.7;

}



*
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

blockquote {
  font-size: 3rem;

}

blockquote q {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
}
blockquote q span {
  will-change: opacity, filter;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(0px);
}
q {

  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
}
q:before {
    content: open-quote;
    margin-right: .8rem;
}
q:after {

}
q:before, q:after {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.text1 {
font-size:80px;
top:160px;

color:white;
position:absolute;
opacity: 0.7;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Yunus Gök</title>
<body class="body">
</head>

<div  class="header"><blockquote><q>Creativity is my way to say hi</q></blockquote></div>
<div  class="text1"><blockquote><q>Welcome on my site</q></blockquote></div>






<script type="text/javascript">

splitWords();


</script>





<div class="background"></div>



<div class="borderimg"></div>

<div class="border"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome , the problem was with queryselectorall